# How can I access the language folders generated by angular i18n?

Tags: angular

I just started using Angular [i18n](https://angular.io/guide/i18n-overview), I managed to get it working, however it generates one build for each language and I don't know how to access them.

I am currently doing this:

```
<div *ngIf="languageCode =='en' || languageCode == 'en-US' else englishlanguage">
    <a href="lang/es/index.html">ES</a>
</div>
<ng-template #englishlanguage>
    <a href="../../index.html">EN</a>
</ng-template>
```

So this redirects me to the folder `lang`, inside `dist`, which contains the `es` folder with all builds for that language. The solution works but I think it's not a good one.

**So here's my question:**  is there any better way of doing that? Is there something like a router like myapp/es and then it redirects to the folder `lang/es` in `dist` folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend looking into https://github.com/ngx-translate/core if you want to integrate i18n in a maintainable and centralized way.